# How can I remove the Duplicate value from arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I created a custom listview with  one Arraylist of String and I haven't added any Duplicate Value in that but when i run it in my phone  the elements after number 9 in the list start to repeat .. so how can i avoid this duplicates.
here are my java codes..

**ListDetails.java**

```
package com.android.mezohn.unl.model;    
import com.android.mezohn.unl.R;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class ListDetails {    
    public static ArrayList<model> getList() {
        ArrayList<model> SystemAuditList = new ArrayList<>();
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S1", "Access Control"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S2", "Contractor Safety"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S3", "PTW Standard"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S4", "Incident Investigation"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S5", "Technology and Subtle change"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S6", "Work at height"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S7", "Confined Spaces"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S8", "Emergency Preparedness and EPI"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S9", "Effluent Treatment and Waste Management "));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S10", "Storage and Handling of Hazardous chemicals"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S11", "Portable Electrical Appliances"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S12", "Machine Guarding"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S13", "Lifting Tools"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S14", "Canteen"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S15", "Personal Change Management"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S16", "Hazard Checklist"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S17", "Hot Work"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S18", "Ladder Safety Checklist"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S19", "LOTO Checklist"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S20", "SBO Checklist"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S21", "Vehicle Marshal system Checklist"));
        SystemAuditList.add(new model("S22", "Gate,Drain and Shutter"));
        return SystemAuditList;            
    } 
}
```

**model.java**

```
package com.android.mezohn.unl.model;


public class model {

    private String Auditcode;
    private String SystemAudit;



    public model(String Auditcode, String SystemAudit ) {
        this.Auditcode = Auditcode;
        this.SystemAudit = SystemAudit;

    }

    public String getAuditcode() { return Auditcode; }

    public void setAuditcode(String Auditcode) {
        this.Auditcode = Auditcode;
    }


    public String getSystemAudit() { return SystemAudit; }

    public void setSystemAudit(String SystemAudit) {
        this.SystemAudit = SystemAudit;
    }
}
```

**SystemAuditAdapter.java**

```
    package com.android.mezohn.unl.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.mezohn.unl.R;
import com.android.mezohn.unl.model.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class SystemauditAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<model> models;


    public SystemauditAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<model> models) {
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return models.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_view,null);

            TextView code = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardcode);
            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
            model model = models.get(position);
            code.setText(model.getAuditcode());
            title.setText(model.getSystemAudit());


        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your adapter code?

Comment: use `Set` instead of `List` ?

Comment: please post your adapter code

Comment: Why not using a HashSet ?
Not sure your issue is in the list, I don't see any duplicated items in this code.
You should use the java convention... Class names start with a capital ( aka Model ) and variables by a lowercase character, systemAuditList.

Comment: show Adapter class please.

Comment: here is my adapter please check the codes

Comment: can you please tell in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an inner class called ViewHolder like below:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView code;
    TextView title;
}
```

Then modify your adapters **getView()** method like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Model model = models.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView ==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_view,null);
        holder.code = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardcode);
        holder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
        converView.setTag(holder);    
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)converView.getTag();
    }
    holder.code.setText(model.getAuditcode());
    holder.title.setText(model.getSystemAudit());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want duplicates on your list you could use [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) allow us store duplicate Object on it.

To remove duplicates object on your Arraylist you could do this:

```
ArrayList<model> SystemAuditList = new ArrayList<>();
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S1", "Access Control"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S2", "Contractor Safety"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S3", "PTW Standard"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S4", "Incident Investigation"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S5", "Technology and Subtle change"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S6", "Work at height"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S7", "Confined Spaces"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S8", "Emergency Preparedness and EPI"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S9", "Effluent Treatment and Waste Management "));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S10", "Storage and Handling of Hazardous chemicals"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S11", "Portable Electrical Appliances"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S12", "Machine Guarding"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S13", "Lifting Tools"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S14", "Canteen"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S15", "Personal Change Management"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S16", "Hazard Checklist"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S17", "Hot Work"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S18", "Ladder Safety Checklist"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S19", "LOTO Checklist"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S20", "SBO Checklist"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S21", "Vehicle Marshal system Checklist"));
SystemAuditList.add(new model("S22", "Gate,Drain and Shutter"));

Set<String> uniqueList = new HashSet<>();
uniqueList.addAll(SystemAuditList);
Log.d("unique list count", String.valueOf(uniqueList.size()));
SystemAuditList.clear(); // clear the list
SystemAuditList.addAll(uniqueList); // add unique list to the Arraylist

return SystemAuditList;
```